# NASM and syntastic: binary output format does not support external references

Tags: plugin-syntastic, filetype-assembly

When I'm running syntastic, I always see the NASM error,

> binary output format does not support external references

This is because I'm assembling with `nasm -f elf64`. How do I instruct syntastic to test the syntax with `-f elf64`? Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I can skirt this issue with an in-file directive.

Comment: `:h syntastic-config-makeprg`, `:h syntastic-config-debug`.

Comment: @lcd047 thanks that worked, self-answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done with,

```
let g:syntastic_nasm_nasm_args = '-f elf64'
```

Thanks to [lcd047](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1577/lcd047) who referenced me in the comments to `:h syntastic-config-makeprg`